# Bootstrap Model Not Working in BlazorServer App

Tags: javascript, html, .net, blazor-server-side

I am learning Blazor, so I am Working on A project where i am Using Bootstrap Model..
Problem Is On click The Actions Buttons On the List, The Model Is Not Opening .. i am Using
IJSRuntime to Open The Model... Below Is My Code

```
                <tbody id="tbody">
                @{
                    if (customers.Count > 0)
                    {
                        int i = 0;

                        @foreach (var customer in customers)
                        {
                            i++;
                            <tr>
                                <td>@customer.Customer_Id </td>
                                <td>@customer.Customer_Name</td>
                                <td>@customer.Customer_Address</td>
                                <td>@customer.Customer_Phone_No</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                            <span><i class='oi oi-cog'></i></span>
                                        </button>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);" @onclick="()=> EditCustomer(customer.Customer_Id)"><i class='oi oi-task'></i> Edit</a></li>
                                            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);" @onclick="()=> EditCustomer(customer.Customer_Id)"><i class='oi oi-delete'></i> Delete</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>


                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        <tr><td colspan="5">No Data Found</td></tr>
                    }
                }

            </tbody>



    public void EditCustomer(int CustomerId)
     {
        JS.InvokeVoidAsync("OpenModal", "#Mdl_Add_Customer");  // where Mdl_Add_Customer is id of the Modal Div
    }
```

Js Function On Another File as General.js

```
window.OpenModal = (Model) => {

let model = document.getElementsById(Model)
let __modal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(model)
__modal.show();
```

}
[image]

on List Item Edit Action I want Popup To Open... Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the modal like this (add the 'new'):

```
var modal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('modalId'));
modal.show();
```